# Opening and printing large files in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to open a local pdf file and print it.It works for  files upto 5 kb,but it takes time to load for big files within 1000ms and hangs.I want it to be dynamic and need not fix the timeout .
I tried window.onload but it does not work.Also i dont want to add any onload event to the printing page.

Is there a efficient solution

```
var win=window.open(printUrl);
setTimeout(function() {
        win.print();
        win.close();
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: The simple answer is: You don't. My suggestion: Stop mucking around how a web browser works, don't open things in new windows. Just provide a normal link the the PDF file and have the user press the print button of the PDF viewer themselves.

Comment: Thanks.We have our own requirement and it should open the print dialog only.

Comment: Requirements don't change how web browsers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an workaround for this.Have used PDF Javascripts and embedded a Javascript to print the file.This makes sure that the file is only printed once the page has been loaded.

I had used PDFbox to parse PDF contents and added the below:

```
PDActionJavaScript javascript = new PDActionJavaScript("this.print();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Today it seems it's not possible to be notified when a PDF file is loaded in your pages.

Events `DOMContentLoad` and `load` are not triggered in `iframes`, `embed`, `object` or popup windows when handling PDF files.

However, there's hope for the future, [the HTML5 specs says about the `embed` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element):

> Fetching the resource must delay the load event of the element's
>   document.

But so far, in Chrome 38 and IE11 it's not true yet, the document `load` event is fired as soon as the HTML is loaded.